# Spring-Batch: retrieve LINE NUMBER during WRITE

Tags: spring-batch

I am reading a text file and writing the data to the database.

My problem is that sometimes I can only know if I want to skip the currently processed line (from the file) when I attempt to write it to the database (for example, when I get an SQL Exception due to duplicate ID's - i.e. the line that I am trying to insert and some line that is already in the database have the same ID).

In that case I need the original line number (for logging purposes) - **any idea how I could get it?**

I've been looking at [this JIRA page](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCH-640) but it looks like it's still under development at the moment.

Comment: So what about [BATCH-863 (LineMapper)](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCH-863)?

Comment: The `LineMapper` (which my code already uses) only handles the "read" part of the job. I.e. from the String to the model object. If I want to return from the "read" with both my model object and the corresponding line number, then I have to define a new class that will be returned from the `LineMapper`: an extension or composition of my model class. This makes everything complicated. If there's a way to retain the line number **in the tasklet level** then it will be more elegant and will let me work with the original model object.

Comment: the writer gets a list of items and there is no guarantee that the items come in like there are read, because an itemReader could skip items or an itemProcessor could filter out items - so the line-number should be in entity/model, otherwise skip/filter would not work

Comment: If the framework retains the line number for each item along the whole tasklet (by tasklet I mean read-process-write for a single item), then skip & filter should work fine. If not, then I can see why I should change my model class to save this data. I am asking if there's something in the framework that retains the line-number data in the tasklet level.

Comment: I am not ware of anything like you need. The problem is that this approach should be generalized also for other readers (DB, JMX, OXM, ...) which not necessarily have "line number" or "record number". So you'd better wrap your domain object onto another one, which holds also the line number.